# Why is added to package.json an empty line

Tags: javascript, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins, package.json

Every time we add a new plugin to **Cordova** `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen` is added inside of package.json to `dependencies` and `plugins` inside `cordova`. Why is necessary twice even if we are not declaring any specific variable for that plugin?

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: It tells to Cordova that the plugin must be loaded. That's why it's there even empty, it contains the plugin name that's not necessarily the same package name.

Comment: thank you Elias, bu why is not necessarily the same package name? I don't get that part, sorry